# Laravel: unable to read configuration files

Tags: php, package, laravel-4, config, configuration-files

I'm developing a Laravel package but I'm not able to read my config files from the `register()` method of my service provider.

If I try `\Config::get("package::file.option")` I get null,
if I try `\Config::get("package::file")` I get an empty array.

Nonetheless I can read them from the `boot()` method!

The followings are my `package()` call inside the `boot()` method and my folder structure:

```
// package() call:
$this->package('cerbero/login');

// package directory structure:
/workbench
    /cerbero
        /login
            /src
                /Cerbero
                    /Login
                        LoginServiceProvider.php
                        ...
                /config
                    main.php
                    oauth.php
                    redis.php
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't directly read config files from `register()` because `$this->app['config']` is given by another service provider.
Rather I have to pass an `$app` instance when I call binding methods.

For example, this works:

```
$this->app->bind('Something', function($app) {
    $config = $app['config']->get('package::file.option');
    return new Something($config);
});
```

Comment: I guess a good way to find out whether your service provider functions correctly and without conflicts is to add it as the very first item in the service provider array. :)

Comment: One thing to note about this answer is that you will have a different something every time you get it. In some cases you may want to have the same object so would need to alter your logic accordingly.